# decrease: compile using android version Xamarin Android, VS

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, version, minimum

I would ask how to decrease minimum version of 'compile using android version'.
I have:
compile using android version ( 2.3[Gingerbred] , 6.0[Marshmallow] )
minimum android to target ( 1.6 - 6.0 )
target android version ( 1.6 - 6.0 )

I would like to set  lower than 2.3 version in 'compile using android version'.
How to set it? Dowload something from manager sdk?

Please help me. I ask because I have amazing problems with my Samsung Galaxy Ace. Any application cannot work on my mobile even code is ok and emulator works well. I am going to change it for elicpse + java soon -,- because VS makes me sad.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is there a need to support < 2.3? There is less than 1.8% devices out using that API set:

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK android manager mark the option Obsolete a select the API for the android you need.

and select the Emulator Manager create a device with a characteristic you need or use the a device with the compilation that your need.

And is you need the minimun target, rigth click in the android project -> properties and edit the minimun that you want
[image: Minimun target]

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up that some API levels were removed in Xamarin.Android 5.0:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.0/#Removal_Of_API_Levels

With this said, I would recommend that you target against API 10 as a minimum. However you should overlook what that means here as you may only want to set your `minSDKLevel` to < 2.3:

http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/

This is also explained in the official Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

To use this, simply download the respective API level from the Android SDK and you're off to the races.