# Xamarin FrameWork SDK and Android

Tags: android, xamarin

i use SDK installer and download android 2.2
but when i try to choose Framework, there is no android 2.2
does someone know how to fix in / download android 2.2 for Xamarin so i could use it as a framework?

Comment: Please make sure you are using the correct Android SDK of Xamarin. You can find the path of Xamarin Android SDK under `Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings`.

Comment: You didn't specify which IDE but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39233972/6146870

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android SDK Manager. From there you can select which framework version should be installed on your machine.

Comment: i installed Andorid 2.2 from there but it wont showed up on the frame work selection

Comment: I seems to me that your Android SDK path is not the one configured in Xamarin Studio/ Visual Studio. Can you check that?